# Using division method how to convert base 5 to base 10

Tags: linear-algebra

Using division method, how can the number $4323$ with base $5$ be converted into a number with base $10$? Using Division method only.

Comment: What is division method?

Comment: What you call the "division method" I might call something different.  What is the division method to you?  Likely, if you can successfully answer that question, you should be able to answer your own original question too.

Comment: What does the division method say? It is far easier to do it just directly (so it will be easy to check your answer).

Comment: As you can see from the comments, your question is not clear.  Please define the Division Method, preferably by giving an explicit  example of how you use it to write a number given in one base in another.

Comment: $\begin{align} 4)5&+3)5+2)5+3\\
&\color{#c00}{\ \ \ 23\ \ \ \ 117\ \ \ \  588}
\end{align}$ $\qquad$

Comment: Voting to close the question because it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your question to respond to the questions the commenters have asked.

Comment: Thanks. By division method, I mean, for example I convert 397 with base 10 to a number with base 9. I divide 397 by 9, get remainder 1 which is least significant digit. I get quotient of 44, again divide it by 9, get remainder of 8, and quotient of 4 which not further divisible by 9 and it is most significant digit. My answer is 481 with base 9. How can I use this method for the numbers with bases I asked in my question. Regards.

Comment: By replacing the appropriate numbers with the ones you need in what you just said... where do you get stuck in trying to do that yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method based on the common method of successive division for converting decimal to binary etc. I'm not sure whether it is what you want.

The integer $10$ is $20_5$. The remainders are stated in base $5$ and then in the target base $10$.

We compute $$4323_5/20_5=213 _5 \text { r } 13_5=8$$ $$213_5/20_5= 10_5 \text { r } 13_5 =8$$$$10_5=5$$

So $$4323_5=588$$

---

To explain the first line (we are doing "long division"), take the first two digits $43_5$ and divide by $20_5$ to get quotient $2_5$ plus remainder $3_5$.

Bring down the next digit to get $32_5$ and divide by $20_5$ to get quotient $1_5$ plus remainder $12_5$.

Now bring down the remaining digit to get $123_5$ and (remembering we are in base $5$) we get quotient $3_5$ and remainder $13_5$.

We put the pieces of the quotient together to get $213_5$. The remainder is $13_5$ which we convert to the decimal digit $8$ which is the remainder on division by $10$ and hence the units digit of the decimal number we are looking for.

We repeat the process with $213_5$ to obtain the second digit (etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this method is superb, but sorry, I could not understand first line. Can you please help me by being a little more elaborate.

Comment: @SanjayMohanBhatnagar I've added some text.